# sap.m.upload.UploadSet not showing Icons

Tags: icons, sapui5, assertion

I'm working on an SAPUI5 sap.m.upload.UploadSet to upload and show uploaded files. I have a Problem there: When I add a File, the Icon is displayed correctly in the UploadSetItem:

[image: When Adding Files, the Icon is shown]

But when I want to show uploaded files, it shows them without icon:

[image: Already uploaded Files not showing Icons]

And I also get this error:

**Assertion failed: Element sap.ui.core.Icon#__item7-icon: Property 'src' (value: '') should be a valid Icon URI (sap-icon://...)**

The UploadSetItem itself has no Icon-Property, so I quess this error has something to do with the Files- Data I receive from the SAP ERP System (no HANA). Why don´t the icons show?

This is how the data looks like:
[image: oData with the Files from Backend]

In my Controller I build the UploadSetItem:

```
createAttachmentItems: function (oData) {
        var oUploadSet = this.getView().byId("attachmentUpl");
        oUploadSet.removeAllItems();
        for (var i in oData.results) {
            console.log("mimetYpe:", oData.results[i].Mimetype, "filename: ", oData.results[i].Filename, )

            var oUploadSetItem = new sap.m.upload.UploadSetItem({
                fileName: oData.results[i].Filename,
                mediaType: oData.results[i].Mimetype,
                uploadState: sap.m.UploadState.Complete,
                thumbnailUrl: null
            });

            var oAttribute1 = new sap.m.ObjectAttribute({
                title: "Hochgeladen von",
                text: oData.results[i].Creatorname,
                active: true
            });
            var oAttribute2 = new sap.m.ObjectAttribute({
                title: "Hochgeladen am",
                text: oData.results[i].Createdon,
                active: false
            });

            var oAttribute3 = new sap.m.ObjectAttribute({
                title: "Dateigröße",
                text: "TODO",
                active: false
            });

            oUploadSetItem.addAttribute(oAttribute1);
            oUploadSetItem.addAttribute(oAttribute2);
            oUploadSetItem.addAttribute(oAttribute3);
            oUploadSet.addItem(oUploadSetItem);
        }
    },
```

And this is the XML code for the UploadSet:

```
<up:UploadSet id="attachmentUpl" instantUpload="false" showIcons="true" uploadEnabled="true" 
   terminationEnabled="true" maxFileNameLength="30" maxFileSize="20" 
   uploadUrl="/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPM_TEST_ODATA_SRV/AttachmentsSet"
   uploadCompleted="onUploadCompleted" 
   fileTypes="pdf,doc,docx,docm,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,jpg,jpeg,png" 
   fileTypeMismatch="onFileTypeMismatch" fileSizeExceeded="onFileSizeExceeded">
</up:UploadSet>
```

Comment: I think the icon is derived from the filename, not from the mime type. Your filename currently has no file extension, this would explain the error message.

Comment: Thank you Marc, the filename extensions that I received from the backend were cut. Our Backend "Guy" has now fixed it, the icons are shown now.